# What parsing strategy is used on Stanford Parser?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm writing a paper where I analyse different available tools for natural language parsing. I found out that two main strategies for parsing are top-down and bottom down.

**I wonder which strategy is used in Stanford Parser?**

I know that they used probabilistic approach there, but is not based on any of bottom-up or top-down?

Comment: Did you try reading the manual? http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is a [CYK parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) (see [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/papers/unlexicalized-parsing.pdf), Section 1), i.e. a bottom up parser.